# Java Half Diamond With Asterisk's (for loops)

Tags: java

Hey im having trouble with my nested for loops in drawing a half diamond in java 
I need to take a user input and make a half diamond with the amount of lines a user specified here is my code

```
public static void diamond(int rows) {
      int m, n;
    for (m = 1; m <= rows; m += 2)
    {
        for (n = 1; n <= m; n++)
        {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
  for (int i = rows; i > 0; i -= 2) {

        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {

            System.out.print("*");
        }
        System.out.println("");
    }
}
```

heres an image of the expected vs actual output

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a logical error. Examine your code:

Let's say they input 5 as the row count.

The first for loop would then cycle through, starting with `m=1,` and then 3, and then 5. The nested for loop is also fine -- it simply draws a '*' an amount of times equal to the value of m.

However, the input was 5, correct? The second for loop sets `i = rows,` so `i` will start out equal to 5. You already drew the longest row, being the one with 5 asterisks in it, in the first for loop. Now, since you are setting `i = 5,` you are drawing another row with 5 asterisks. What you want as your second for loop is this:

`for(int i = rows - 2; i > 0; i-=2){
...`

This way the second for loop does not draw the longest row **again** as the first for loop already did.

Comment: thank you so much I didn't examine that closely enough! I appreciate it!

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class HalfDiamond
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int n;
        Scanner obj=new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter the number of Rows:");
        n=obj.nextInt();
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i=i+2)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(i%2==1)
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for(int i=n-2;i>=1;i=i-2)
        {
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
            {
                if(i%2==1)
                    System.out.print("*");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Solution {
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Write your code here
        
        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        int n = scn.nextInt();
        
        System.out.println("*");
        
        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                System.out.print(j);
            
            for(int j=i-1;j>=1;j--)
                System.out.print(j);
            
            
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        
        for(int i=n-1;i>=1;i--)
        {
            System.out.print("*");
            for(int j=1;j<=i;j++)
                System.out.print(j);
            for(int j=i-1;j>=1;j--)
                System.out.print(j);
            System.out.println("*");
        }
        System.out.println("*");    
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should help a lot its the best answer/example you'll find...take a look at it. It has everything that is needed to make a half diamond pointing down.

```
  for (int line = n - 1; line >= 1; line--)
  {
      for (int spaces = n - line; spaces >= 0; spaces--)
          System.out.print(" ");

      for(int i = 1; i < line + line; i++)
          System.out.print("*");

      System.out.println();
  }

  keyboard.close();
```

}
}

Answer (score -1):

This might help you.

```
for(int i = 0;i<5;i++) {
    for(int j= 0;j<i;j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}

for(int i = 5;i>0;i--) {
    for(int j=0;j<i;j++) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    System.out.println("");
}
```